# Flex Search Interface: Load XML or Query DB

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript, cairngorm

For a Flex application that is used to search and display results (no write operations), I am currently storing data in a relational database, 
but rather than querying the DB via the app, I am doing a nightly write of the data, including its relationships, to an XML file.

Then, through Flex, I am loading that XML file, parsing it into custom Objects, and "querying" those objects as necessary.

It works really well -- basically filtering an ArrayCollection of these Objects based on search criteria.

Versus querying the DB, full text search, for instance, is extremely fast in this scenario.

But what are some potential drawbacks? How valid is this approach? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: ... Sorry, there is no short answer.

The long answer is this:  Architecture decisions always involve some kind of trade-off.  What the right decision for your application is, depends mostly on your content and your system's overall design.

The only thing I can say for sure is: What you are doing now prevents a clean separation of concerns.

For example: If you did the searching on the server, you could possibly change field names, etc. in the database without your client ever knowing it, because you could adjust the actual data output to match the "old" model, even if the query were completely different. The client would take care of displaying the data, the server would take care of persisting and retrieving it.  This is what you would probably want, if you develop in a larger team, or if your application is long-running, has complex transactions and/or changes behavior often, for example in an enterprise scenario.  These scenarios usually take into account a greater strain on the server and thus a need for more powerful hardware, because hardware cost is not the most pressing concern for larger companies.

Depending on how large your complete data set is, it would also reduce network load significantly, because you wouldn't need to transfer all of it to the client, but only relevant results. So, if your server's network connection is limited, or your users tend to have slower connections, this would probably be a good idea.

On the other hand: If you search and query inside your client app, the way you describe it, you take load off the database and the web server, which is not always a bad thing, especially if your server capacity is limited, and performance is crucial.

But aside from increasing overall network traffic, it also means you rely on the client computer a great deal more: a) It has to be fast enough to handle the search, and b) you always have to (re-)deploy an updated app to the user, every time your data model changes even slightly.  This is quite possibly a major source of errors, so you would have to implement some sort of version checking to prevent an outdated client from connecting to the server and/or disable browser caching.

So in the end, you have to weigh the pros and cons and then decide which solution suits your needs best.  And you might want to consider using a dedicated search engine like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) as a third option.